# Spring 4.3 allows query params to override path variables from @RequestMapping

Tags: spring-mvc

Apparenly, Spring (4.3) accepts query parameters preferentially over path variables, allowing them to override the path variables when using `@RequestMapping` with path variables, and binding the request values to a model class. Given a controller like below:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloWorldController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/hi/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Greeting sayHello(
            @Valid HelloParams helloParams) {
        return new Greeting(helloParams.toString());
    }
```

If we request a URL such as `/hi/good?name=bad`, we will see that the `name` param takes the value "bad". Thus, the "good" value which was present in the URL path in the `{name}` position gets ignored or overridden by the query parameter. If we remove the "name" query parameter, we get the "good" value instead.

Note: I am using a model class so that I can do validation on multiple fields of the model. I can't fix this just by using `@PathVariable` on a simple method parameter.

**Why is this?** I don't see any mention of this behavior in the documentation.

**Is there any workaround to prevent it from happening?**

This behavior by Spring also appears to be confusing Springfox Swagger: in this case the Swagger UI generates URLs such as: `/hi/{name}?name=foo` (with literal curly brackets present in the URL). And, oddly enough, it works due to the behavior described above. However, it's misleading to people who use the API because they should use path params!

Comment: where is your `@RequestParam` and `@PathVariable` defined in the sayHello method?

Comment: @AmitKBist it's not, and doesn't need to be. Spring will automatically bind parameters by name to JavaBean properties on `HelloParams`.

Answer (score 2):

It is exactly same as my problem. My Solution is *@ApiImplicitParams*. My Spring Boot Sample(with Lombok) code is below.

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Test API.")
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/{memberId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ApiImplicitParams({
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "memberId", value = "member identification number", paramType = "path", dataType = "long", required = true)
})
public ResponseEntity<String> testMethod(@Valid CommandObject command) {
    return "hello, world~"
}

@Setter
@Getter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CommandObject {
    private long memberId
}
```

@ApiImplicitParam's name is the field name of CommandObject. Important part is **paramType**. It's value is whether *path* or *query*. *path* for path variables and *query* for query parameters.

Also, refer to documentation: http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.5.X/apidocs/index.html?io/swagger/annotations/ApiModelProperty.html

Comment: Ah, interesting, I see that `@ApiImplicitParams` is a Swagger annotation. I'll have to give that a try some time. Do you use Springfox, and is it able to generate the correct URL in the UI?

Comment: Yes, I'm using springfox, and I could be generating correct URL in swagger UI by @ApiImplicitParams.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use same variable for both requestparam and pathvariable, then you can create method like below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hi/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String sayHello(@PathVariable(value="name") String name1, @RequestParam(value="name") String name2)
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood my question. I don't want Spring to pay attention to the query params at all, only the path. Also, I need to use a model class so that I can do validation on multiple values in the class. That doesn't work if you use individual/separate simple parameters.